# Can I mount this weight lifting rack to 3 studs instead of 4?

Tags: walls, mount

My wife bought me [this](https://www.roguefitness.com/monster-lite-rml-390-fullw-fold-back-wall-mount-power-rack) Rogue Power Rack. It looks amazing, but the place we both want to mount it to is **not** the garage, it's a bedroom in our house in Phoenix. It's a new-build and the studs in the wall are 24" apart. The 24" spacing means we could only fit 3 studs in the span of the stringer, which specifies 4.

The stringer instructions seem to be relatively general and I'm hoping I'd be able to mount it to 3 studs instead of 4, since this is more of a cage and not a rack, where most of the load will be on the 4 legs and not the wall. Re-racking might be the only risk, correct? I don't plan on doing any kipping, and I'm not a very big lifter -- can't imagine I'll ever squat over 350.

Comment: You probably should ask the manufacturer this question.

Comment: Can't imagine it'd be a code vio to put this in a spare bedroom, @JimStewart, is that what you're implying? I could see an issue if it's _not_ on a concrete slab (the weight might be an issue)...

Comment: Does it use all four studs for mounting(screws/bolts) in each stud, or just the two outside studs?  If four studs are needed for mounting, @FreeMan answer should work.

Comment: I had to reword that. I kept reading it as "a bedroom in Phoenix" and wondering where the rest of the house was...

Comment: Ah, I should have clarified that the garages in Phoenix are all spaced at 16", and other rooms at 24" for studs. Not sure why I expected the rest of the world to know that. Thank you.

Comment: @crip659 - it can reach 3 studs, but instructions specify 4, but no details on what kind of rack it's for. A rack with two legs, like a squat stand, might need 4, but I'd imagine a squat cage sends most of the load to the ground and I don't need all 4.

Comment: Was asking more about the mounting holes, are they just at the ends or where each 16" stud would be?

Comment: Ah, they're just horizontal cutouts. I'd be able to hit all 3 studs, four times (two in each stringer, at about 6" vertical spacing in each one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the manufacturer can't help you out with specifics for your 24" OC studs, then I'd suggest running 2x4" or 2x6" horizontally across the wall at each level where there are to be bolts mounting this to the wall. Lag screw the horizontal boards to the studs, then you can screw the rack to the studs at each of the 4 locations they require.

4 studs at 16" OC would be a 4' span, as would 3 studs at 24" OC. In that respect, yes, they're the same. However, 4 studs actually supply more lumber to actually support the rack. I'd suggest you would want to have your horizontal boards span 4 studs, screwing it into each one, then you can put the rack anywhere in that 72" span you'd like.